# Auto number an attribute based on multiple attributes

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

I have a transaction like this

[image]

And I have a web panel using Work With Plus to insert data into the transaction
[image: web panel]

I want to auto number the attribute `TmpltId` based on the `SalOutCd7Plc` and `BseCd` like this:
Example:

```
SalOutCd7Plc = 1 and BseCd = 1 -> TmpltId = 1 then continue if SalOutCd7Plc = 1 and BseCd = 1 -> TmpltId = 2
But if SalOutCd7Plc = 1 and BseCd = 2 -> TmpltId = 1 and continue
If SalOutCd7Plc = 2 and BseCd = 1 -> TmpltId = 1 and continue
```

Something like that. How can I achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To autonumber the attribute TmpltId you may create a procedure with the following:

**Rules**:

```
parm(in:&SENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc,in:&SENSY0470M_BseCd,out:&SENSY0470M_TmpltId);
```

**Source**:

```
For each SENSY0470M order SENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc SENSY0470M_BseCd (SENSY0470M_TmpltId)
where SENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc = &SENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc
where SENSY0470M_BseCd = &SENSY0470M_BseCd
   &SENSY0470M_TmpltId = SENSY0470M_TmpltId + 1
   exit
when none
   &SENSY0470M_TmpltId = 1
EndFor
```

Then, in your web panel before inserting you can call the procedure to get the new SENSY0470M_TmpltId

```
&NEW_SENSY0470M_TmpltId = Procedure.Udp(&SENSY0470M_SalOutCd7Plc, &SENSY0470M_BseCd)
```